# If $X$ is Stein and $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})\neq 0$ then there are no principal divisors?

Tags: complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

There is a result that claims: If $X$ is a Stein manifold and $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})=0$ then for any divisor $D$ there is a meromorphic function $f$ such that $(f)=D$.

What happens if $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})\neq 0$ ? Is there any divisor that can not be of the form $(f)$ for some meromorphic function?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is well known as the Cousin problem II.

If $M$ is a Stein manifold of dimension $n$, the exact sequence of sheaves
$$0\to\mathbb Z\to \mathcal O_M\to \mathcal O^*_M\to 0$$
yields a morphism of groups in cohomology (part of a long exact sequence) $$H^1(M,\mathcal O_M)\to H^1(M,\mathcal O^*_M)\to H^2(M,\mathbb Z)\to H^1(M,\mathcal O_M).$$
We have $H^1(M,\mathcal O_M)$ and $H^2(M,\mathcal O_M)$ both vanish thanks to Cartan's theorem B. Since $H^1(M,\mathcal O^*_M)$ can be identified to $Pic(M)$, the group of line bundles on $M$, we get the isomorphism $$c_1:Pic(M)\to H^2(M,\mathbb Z).$$

We then absolutely have $Pic(M)=0,$ thus any line bundle $\mathcal O(D)$ corresponding to the divisor $D$ is trivial.

Due to a classical result, a divisor $D$ is principal iff $\mathcal O (D)$ is trivial ***(A)***, we are done.

If $H^2(M, \mathbb Z)\neq 0$, we absolutely can find a non-principal divisor $D$ when $\mathcal O(D)$ is not trivial thanks to ***(A)***.

Comment: Dear @Steve Thank you very much!!

Comment: @Framate, Sure thing. Just please remember to accept the answer when you are satisfied that you accept it. :)